# Is it possible to launch a NoSQL cluster with Dynamodb locally(downloadable) and not in amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, cluster-computing

Actually I am not very familiar with Dynamodb and I would like to launch a NoSQL database with local Dynamodb (downloadable version) but not hosted on amazon AWS. I would appreciate it if someone could let me know is it possible to make such a clustered or does downloadable version of Dynamodb support to be cluster locally ?

Answer (score 2):

You can very easily run DynamoDB locally, but it only supports running a single instance—not a cluster. It's intended to be used for local testing/debugging.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is provided as a hosted service. Does not exist a DynamoDB code that you can download and install to use as a host or service provider.

As part of SDK for a lot of languages, AWS Team developed some wrappers that permits you to execute local versions of DynamoDB to test your particular code. These wrappers respect the DynamoDB API contract. In that case you can code to the DynamoDB interface and get the responses like it were hosted in AWS environment. But you can't host any database or even serve data as a service using this solutions.